# Can someone explain the Priority Q algorithm

Tags: scheduling, priority-queue

If we have a Process A with an index arrival 1 and priority level 2 and a Process B with index arrival 2 and priority 1 which one is being processed first? Every example I've seen has (conviniently) a high priority process arriving first.

Answer (score 0):

Higher priority one processed before lower priority one.... how many answers will be made before I submit this one...

Answer (score 0):

If the queue is empty and no jobs are currently being processed, then if Process A (priority 2) is queued at time index 1 then it will be removed and processed. If Process B (priority 1) arrives at time index 2, then it will have to wait until Process A is complete.

If there is a job currently being processed and Process A (priority 2) is queued at time index 1, and then Process B (priority 1) is queued at time index 2, then Process B will be dequeued and processed as soon as the current job is done. Assuming, of course, no higher priority job is queued before the existing job is complete.

This all assumes that you don't have multiple processing threads, and there's no rule that lower priority jobs are suspended when higher priority jobs appear in the queue.